# Manipulate input_text in watson conversation

Tags: spring, spring-el, watson-conversation, watson

I designing Watson conversation where I'm trying to manipulate user's input if confidence goes lower than 85% and there may be a possible word which is lowering the confidence and I'm saving those possible word in entities.

```
{
  "context": {
     "input_text": "<? input_text.replaceAll(entities['toBeExtracted'].literal,'') ?>"
   },
  "output": {}
}
```

The above mentioned is not working

**Note: I already have a "jump to" which loops back**

Answer (score 1):

Manipulating `input_text` internally has no effect on `input_text` that was received in the request that is processed by the classifier that extracts intents and entities out of it. In a nutshell you cannot do this internally inside dialog nodes, but you need to change the text client side and create a new request with "corrected" text. But a better solution than this is to simply add text that was miss-classified as another example to the intent it should be classified as.

Answer (score -1):

I think that if you put in the trigger condition:

```
    if intents[0].confidence < 0.85 or @toBeExtracted
```

It will already give what you want, without the context part. Give a look at this [site](https://sodoherty.ai/2016/09/05/handling-low-confidence-answers-in-conversation/), because it helped me a lot.

Comment: I need that entity removed from the user input